# How to access C# struct property by variable name?

Tags: c#, struct, properties

How do I access the properties of a struct based on a string variable defined by the user at runtime?

I know it's not ideal. This is just a simple assignment.

I wanted to use an enum, but from what I understand I can't support the storing of values of type double.

If there's another best practice to use, please suggest also.

Thanks for the help!

````
using System;

public struct Rates
{
   
public const double charterdaily = 1000;
public const double charterhourly = 400;
public const double charterdistance = 3.5;
public const double minibusdaily = 925;
public const double minibushourly = 360;
public const double minibusdistance = 3.25;
public const double sprinterdaily = 850;
public const double sprinterhourly = 320;
public const double sprinterdistance = 3;
public const double partybusdaily = 1000;
public const double partybushourly = 400;
public const double partybusdistance = 3.5; 
public const double sedandaily = 7000;
public const double sedanhourly = 240;
public const double sedandistance = 2.5;
public const double suvdaily = 625;
public const double suvhourly = 200;
public const double suvdistance = 2.25; 
public const double limodaily = 550;
public const double limohourly = 400;
public const double limodistance = 3.5;
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       
        int numberOfVehicles;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter # of vehicles: ");
        numberOfVehicles = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        string vehicleType;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter vehicle type. Values accepted: charter, minibus, sprinter, partybus, sedan, suv, limo.");
        vehicleType = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

        string pricingMethod;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter pricing method. Values accepted: daily, hourly, distance.");
        pricingMethod = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

        double pricingMethodUnits; //double because we want to support partial mile distances


 switch (pricingMethod)
      {
          case "daily":

              Console.WriteLine("Enter number of DAYS you are renting: ");
              pricingMethodUnits = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
              break;
          
          case "hourly":

              Console.WriteLine("Enter number of HOURS you are renting:");
              pricingMethodUnits = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
              break;

          case "distance":

              Console.WriteLine("Enter expected DISTANCE traveled in miles: ");
              pricingMethodUnits = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
              break;


          default:
              Console.WriteLine("Invalid pricing method value entered");            
              
              break;
      }


        string enumString = vehicleType + pricingMethod;
        Console.WriteLine("enumString value: " + enumString );
        
        //this is where I want to access the Rate struct by the passed in enum string
        Console.WriteLine(Rates."{enumString}");
     
    }
}```
````

Comment: Have you considered using a `Dictionary<string, double>`? You would populate it in constructor somewhere, and then you could just do `double rate = rateLookup[enumString];`

Comment: Why don't you just create a `Vehicle` class with the properties and put them into a list? Why do you want/need to use a struct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using `static` `Dictionary<string, double>`:

```
  private static readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<string, double> Rates =
    new Dictionary<string, double>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) {
      { "charterdaily",  1000},
      { "charterhourly", 400},
      //TODO: Add all the pairs here
    };
```

Then you can read value from the dictionary by its key

```
  //this is where I want to access the Rate struct by the passed in enum string
  Console.WriteLine(Rates[enumString]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below line of code for dynamically selecting the struct properties values:

```
 // Your sample code 
 string enumString = vehicleType + pricingMethod;
    Console.WriteLine("enumString value: " + enumString );
 
 // Code to get the values
 var data = typeof(Rates).GetFields().Where(x=>x.Name==enumString)
                 .Select(a => a.GetRawConstantValue()
                 .ToString()).ToArray().FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: This might normally work, however the need is for "values of type double" (quoted from question).